# Thingsboard Failed to Start | Application startup failed on ubuntu

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, thingsboard

I have built thingsboard from sources, installed deb on ubuntu everything was running fine. For some reason I had to restart ubuntu, but after then i am getting following error on

```
sudo service thingsboard start
```

results in

```
  ERROR 2127 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application startup failed 2018-06-26 09:17:55.066 ERROR 3437 ---
 [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter    : Error
 starting Tomcat context. Exception:
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException.
 Message: Error creating bean with name
 'thingsboardSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed
 through field 'restAuthenticationProvider'; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
 Error creating bean with name 'restAuthenticationProvider' defined in
 URL
 [jar:file:/usr/share/thingsboard/bin/thingsboard.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/org/thingsboard/server/service/security/auth/rest/RestAuthenticationProvider.class]:
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
 nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
 Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
 dependency expressed through field 'relationService'; nested exception
 is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
 Error creating bean with name 'baseRelationService': Unsatisfied
 dependency expressed through field 'relationDao'; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
 Error creating bean with name 'jpaRelationDao': Unsatisfied dependency
 expressed through field 'relationRepository'; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
 creating bean with name 'relationRepository': Cannot create inner bean
 '(inner bean)#6d5d8247' of type
 [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting
 bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
 creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6d5d8247': Cannot resolve
 reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor
 argument; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
 creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
 resource
 [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
 javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default]
 Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory 2018-06-26 09:17:55.199 ERROR
 3437 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               :
 Application startup failed
```

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: In my case it was insufficient memory available on the system

Comment: may be you need to execute the script `sudo /usr/share/thingsboard/bin/install/install.sh --loadDemo`